# Latin Hypercube sampling with constraints

Tags: python, scipy, sampling

I want to generate say about 500 samples of 36 variables using Latin Hypercube sampling to ensure good coverage of the parameter spaces.

I also want to ensure each sample meets some constraint.

```
from scipy.stats import qmc
import numpy as np

def unpack(params: np.ndarray) -> tuple[
    float,       # p
    np.ndarray,  # variable means
    np.ndarray,  # standard errors
    np.ndarray,  # correlation coefficients
    np.ndarray,  # covariance
]:
    (p,), means, dev_diag, X_triu = np.split(params, (1, 8, 15))
    dev = np.diag(dev_diag)
    n = dev_diag.size
    X = np.zeros((n, n))
    X[np.triu_indices(n=n, k=1)] = X_triu
    X += X.T + np.eye(n)
    cov = dev @ X @ dev

    return p, means, dev, X, cov

def positive_definite(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    p, means, dev, X, cov = unpack(params)
    return np.real(np.linalg.eigvals(cov))

def init_pop_qml(bounds, popsize,multipler=10):
    limits = np.array(bounds, dtype='float').T
    parameter_count = len(bounds)
    num_population_members = popsize * parameter_count

    sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=parameter_count,seed=123456)
    sample = sampler.random(n=num_population_members*multipler)
    l_bounds = limits[0]
    u_bounds = limits[1]
    samples = qmc.scale(sample, l_bounds, u_bounds)

    checks = np.zeros((num_population_members*multipler, 7))
    for row in range(num_population_members*multipler):
        check = positive_definite(samples[row, :])
        checks[row, :] = check
    population = samples[(checks > 0).all(axis=1), :]
    while population.shape[0] < num_population_members:
        sample2 = sampler.random(n=num_population_members*multipler)
        samples2 = qmc.scale(sample2, l_bounds, u_bounds)
        checks2 = np.zeros((num_population_members*multipler, 7))
        for row in range(num_population_members*multipler):
            check2 = positive_definite(samples2[row, :])
            checks2[row,:] = check2
        population2 = samples2[(checks2 > 0).all(axis=1), :]
        population = np.vstack((population, population2))
        print(population.shape)
    return population[0:num_population_members,:]

bounds = (((0.0, 1.0),) * 8 + ((0.0, 1.0),) + ((0.0, 0.5),) * 6 + ((-1.0,1.0),)*21)
init_pop=init_pop_qml(bounds, 15, 10)
print(init_pop)
```

First, this takes quite long time to get 500 samples.

Second, the samples in the end may not have good coverage of the parameter space because of the constraint, so using constraint may lose the purpose of using Latin Hypercube sampling.

How can I improve sampling here?

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76106183/scipy-latin-hypercube-sampling-with-constraints), but there is no answer.